ATA VS TOKEN ACCOUNT
Everything was totally fine until, i came across some code. i'm not able to figure out the difference between Token Account and an ATA.
ATA's are nothing but are used to store tokens of a specific mint. Now what are these Token Accounts? can someone explain me in simple terms. and can you clarify are all the ATA's are token accounts?

Associated token account is just a token account which it's address is derived deterministically. And there's more features about this.

A user can have multiple token accounts as much as possible could be made by one mint account. But with associated token account, a user can have ONE main token account for ONE mint account for his/herself. It makes other users to send tokens more easily to the other, because there's just one token account to send!
When trying to send token to the other, the other should already have the token account. If it doesn't exist at that time, the transaction will revert. But with associated token account, the other user doesn't have to have the token account when trying to receive the token. It could be created by the sender deterministically. So there would be no transaction failure.

So you just can understand that the associated token account is the extend of the token account. Here is the official docs about this.

when you say there can be multiple token accounts of same mint. i didn't understand that point very well. Because for a token mint there can be one ATA where it's used to store balance of the speicif token mint right? now when you say there can be multiple token accounts of same mint what does it mean. does every token account store the balance of the same mint. it's just so confusing for me

@iamjoey.sol Yes, one wallet can have one ATA for one MINT. And one wallet can have multiple TA (Token Accounts) for one MINT. So it's more comfortable to use ATA than TA. Here's the official ref(https://solana.com/docs/core/tokens#token-account).
